# Mascara moeda com jquery

Tags: jquery, mask

eu preciso de uma marca para um campo com valor , estou usando o jquery.maskinput
funciona perfeito mas eu tenho que digitar o valor inteiro!

oque estou procurando é uma mascara que preencha automático " R$ $var.000,00 "

por exemplo, se eu tiver um valor de 500mil , com maskinput eu teria que digita

50000000

mas com a mascara que eu citei acima so teria que digitar

500

alguem tem alguma dica sobre isso??

Answer (score 2):

Sem fazer qualquer validação, apenas para conseguir o que você citou.

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function() {

var v = $(this).val();

if (parseInt(v.length) === 3) {

$(this).val((v * 1000).toLocaleString('pt-br', {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}));

}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
```

Comment: eu agradeço a resposta rapida, entao os valores deste input varia muito, entre 50mil ate 4milhoes  , entao teria que ser um tipo de mascara onde acompanha o valor, o que vc passou funcionou mas so com valores entre 100mil a 999mil

Answer (score 0):

Existe um plugin `jQuery` que talvez possa ajudar, se chama `jquery-maskmoney`, segue o link:

http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/

Comment: tentei utilizar o maskmaney mas n consegui editar para deixar como eu quero :(